# Recursing data into a 2 dimensional array in PHP 5

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm getting bamboozled by "for each" loops and two dimensional arrays, and I'm a php newb so please bear with me (and ignore any variables with the word "image" - it's all about the mp3s, I just didn't change it from the xml tutorial)

I found a php function on the net that list files in a directory, the output of which is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => audio/1.mp3
  [1] => audio/2.mp3
  [2] => audio/3.mp3
  [3] => audio/4.mp3
  [4] => audio/5.mp3
)
```

As expected.

And another that lists some info about mp3 files.

```
$mp3datafile = 'audio/1.mp3';
$m = new mp3file($mp3datafile);
$mp3dataArray = $m->get_metadata();
print_r($mp3dataArray);
unset($mp3dataArray);
```

The output of which is

```
Array
(
  [Filesize] => 31972
  [Encoding] => CBR
  [etc]
)
```

In order to automatically build RSS for a podcast, I need to generate XML for each item. So far so good.

This is how I'm making the xml

```
foreach ($imagearray as $key => $val) {
      $tnsoundfile = $xml_generator->addChild('item');
      $tnsoundfile->addChild('title', $podcasttitle);

      $enclosure = $tnsoundfile->addChild('enclosure');
      $enclosure->addAttribute('url', $val);     // that's the filename
      $enclosure->addAttribute('length', $mp3dataArray[Filesize]); // << Length is file length, not time. But later I also need $mp3dataArray[Length mm:ss] for duration tag.
      $enclosure->addAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');

      $tnsoundfile->addChild('guid', $path_to_image_dir.'/'.$val);
  }
```

(The above has been truncated, I realise it's not proper xml right now, but it was just to show what was going on).

Perfect. But I need to do it for as many files as there are in the directory.

So, I have an array of the names of the files in the directory in $mp3data
And, I have an array of mp3 data in $mp3dataArray from one iteration of the get_metadata() function.

If I do the following, then I get a nice list of the mp3 data of the 5 files in the directory:

```
foreach ($mp3data as $key => $val) {
$mp3datafile = $val;
$m = new mp3file($mp3datafile);
$mp3dataArray = $m->get_metadata();
print_r($mp3dataArray);
unset($mp3dataArray);
}
```

As expected.

Where I'm struggling, and have been for most of the day in spite of reading many forums and tutorials, is how to populate the "second dimension" of the array, so that it goes through 1,2,3,4 and 5.mp3 (or however many there are), extracts the metadata, then allows me to use it in the xml section above.

Here's what I have

```
foreach ($mp3data as $key => $val) {
$mp3datafile = $val;
$m = new mp3file($mp3datafile);
$mp3dataArray = $m->get_metadata();
$mp3testarray = array($mp3dataArray);
}
 print_r($mp3dataArray);
```

Shouldn't that line print_r($mp3dataArray); give me a nice list of 5 lots of mp3 data, in the way it did when I recursed through the loop as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$mp3testarray = array();
foreach ($mp3data as $key => $val) {
    $mp3datafile = $val;
    $m = new mp3file($mp3datafile);
    $mp3dataArray = $m->get_metadata();
    $mp3testarray[] = array($mp3dataArray);
}
// check $mp3testarray[] 
print_r($mp3testarray);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works a treat. As soon as I can rate it up, I will! I'd have thanked you sooner but "notify of reply by email" doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop, you are reassigning `$mp3dataArray`. You probably want to append to the array rather than just replace it each time.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?php

$mp3dataArray = array();                         //get array ready for each file
foreach ($mp3data as $key => $val) {             //for each file in dir
    $m = new mp3file($val);                      //get current file's mp3 info
    $mp3dataArray[] = array($m->get_metadata()); //store current mp3 info in next array element
}
var_dump($mp3dataArray);                         //display all of the array's contents

?>
```